# How to Create Relationship between two Different Column in Neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, nosql

I am trying to initiate a **relationship between two columns** in **Neo4j**. my dataset is a **CSV file** with **two-column** refers to **Co-Authorship** and I want to Construct a Network of it. I already load the data, return them and match them.

**Loading**

```
load csv from 'file:///conet1.csv' as rec
```

**return the data**

```
create (:Guys {source: rec[0], target: rec[1]})
```

now I need to **Construct the Collaboration Network** of data by making a **relationship between source and target columns**. What do you propose for the purpose?

I was able to make a relationship between mentioned columns in NetworkX graph libray in python like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
df = pd.read_excel('Colab.csv', columns= ['source', 'target'])
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'source','target', 'weight')
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your use case, I do not believe you should be creating `Guys` nodes just to store relationship info. Instead, the graph-oriented approach would be to create an `Author` node for each author and a relationship (say, of type `COLLABORATED_WITH`) between the co-authors.

This might work for you, or at least give you a clue:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///conet1.csv' AS rec
MERGE (source:Author {id: rec[0]})
MERGE (target:Author {id: rec[1]})
CREATE (source)-[:COLLABORATED_WITH]->(target)
```

*If it is possible that the same relationship could be re-created, you should replace the `CREATE` with a more expensive `MERGE`. Also, a work can have any number of co-authors, so having a relationship between every pair may be sub-optimal depending on what you are trying to do; but that is a separate issue.*